# How to see full HttpPost Request using Apache HttpClient on Android

Tags: android, forms, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

So I have code that contstructs a HttpPost request like the following...

```
public LoginForm apa;
....
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", 
SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
HttpParams httpparams = new BasicHttpParams();
SingleClientConnManager mgr = new SingleClientConnManager(httpparams, schemeRegistry);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(mgr, httpparams);
try {
  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  for(String i : apa.getParams().keySet()){
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(i, apa.getParams().get(i)));
}
List<NameValuePair> cookies = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String i : apa.getCookies().keySet()){
  sb.append(i);
  sb.append("=");
  sb.append(apa.getCookies().get(i));
  sb.append(";");
}
// Trying to remove last ;
String cookie = sb.toString();
cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.length()-1);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httppost.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);
// Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

It isn't logging in quite as I would expect so is there a way to output the entire request (headers and all) to match it up with the one I see in my Chrome Dev Tools? Am I over thinking this? Is there a form login library for Android or Java in general? Do I need content-length added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Printing the headers is easy - you can list them using method `getAllHeaders`.
If you need to print `HttpEntity`, you can use method `writeTo` to write whole entity into `ByteArrayOutputStream` and create a String using `toString`.

Comment: But there isn't any baked in functionality for this. Iterating and Unencoding are the responsibility of the user?

Comment: I don't know about any other:-) I have successfully debugged multipart post containing binary image using these methods. It gives you raw post data, toString method has encoding parameter so you can print in utf-8.